# CSS shows up correct but isn't correct until refresh, issue with floats

Tags: html, css

I am building a page and having some trouble with the media queries. The media queries work fine, but the normal CSS doesn't resume until the page is refreshed. Here is the page in question: http://diamaxinc.com/build2/safety-and-technology?lang=EN

If you make your browser size smaller you'll see the section that says 'Product Technology' stacks nicely. Upon making the browser bigger again it doesn't resume the normal CSS until page is refreshed. I've had this issue previously with floats, what can I do to remedy this? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` to the img for desktop view. When your css sets `float:none` to the image in mobile view, it doesn't reset when resizing browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make `#technology #product_tech_upper .inner-shadow img` float from left and add a clearfix class to the parent